# How to solve Google login security error in Firefox?

Tags: security, firefox, google-signin, google-oauth

Current versions of firefox throw security error even in official Google examples.

[Firefox security error in google oAuth login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgNgJ.png)

You can try to open it in Firefox. The official document is here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#add_a_google_sign-in_button

You can find the address of the page with the button itself in the source code of the given page. I wanted to provide it but Stackoverflow was against posting two urls in one question.

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/identity/sign-in/web/demos/signin_contextual_simple?hl=en -> link to the actual button

Comment: On some instances of the same version of Firefox there is no such error.